# Fetch All the Status for Pipeline in Azure ADO Using Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to fetch the status of pipeline in Azure ADO using rest API.

I tried using GET status API using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/status/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

But it gives only the status of the last completed job.

I am looking to fetch status of all the runs of the pipeline. Could you please guide me and help with the relevant API.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Get status API only shows the latest run status of this pipeline.

As a work around, you could use Get Runs List API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/%7BpipelineId%7D/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

And check the result value from the response body.

[image]